# Installed Python from source and cannot import Tkinter - how to install?

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-2.6

I installed Python 2.6 from source for software testing (2.7 was preinstalled on my Linux distro). However, I cannot import Tkinter within 2.6, I suppose because it doesn't know where to find Tk. How do I either help 2.6 find the existing Tkinter install or reinstall Tkinter for 2.6?

Comment: I solved this by adding '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' to lib_dirs in setup.py, then rebuilding python.

Comment: I should convert your comment to an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' to lib_dirs in setup.py, then rebuilding python

Answer (score 1):

Install the TCL and Tk development files and rebuild Python.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using `pip-2.6 install package`?

Comment: Tkinter isn't available on pip IIRC.